# Symfony2.8 : installation not complete

Tags: php, symfony

I downloaded Symfony2 et when I create a project `/var/www/html# php ../symfony.phar new MyProject 2.8`

At the end, I have this message :

```
Preparing project...

 ✕  Symfony 2.8.2 was successfully installed but your system doesn't meet its
 technical requirements! Fix the following issues before executing
 your Symfony application:

 * date.timezone setting must be set
   > Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).

 After fixing these issues, re-check Symfony requirements executing this command:

   php Projet_miage/app/check.php

 Then, you can:

    * Change your current directory to /var/www/html/Projet_miage

    * Configure your application in app/config/parameters.yml file.

    * Run your application:
    1. Execute the php app/console server:run command.
    2. Browse to the http://localhost:8000 URL.

* Read the documentation at http://symfony.com/doc
```

But why ?

(I have xampp and I am on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because to make your application working properly, Symfony need some specific PHP configuration.

Find your php.ini by running:

```
php --ini
```

This will output something like :

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /path/to/php
>   Loaded Configuration File:         /path/to/php/php.ini

Then, open it:

```
nano /path/to/php/php.ini
```

Find the line `date.timezone` and change it to :

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

Of course, if "Europe/Paris" is not your timezone, you can replace by yours.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the timezone in your `php.ini`

`date.timezone = " Europe/Paris"`

Restart xampp after that